# Does SVM suffer from Quasi-complete separation or perfect separation?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, separation

Are SVMs, which use the hinge loss, suffer from Quasi-complete separation or perfect separation? Why or why not? Could you please give mathematical justification?

Comment: Are you talking about perfect separability like in logistic regression (Hauck-Donner effect)?

Comment: Yes. I am just wondering if this thing would also affect SVM as well.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem... Hint: does the SVM with hinge loss include a regularization term?